# Old drill logs with unknown coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I have old drill logs with holes easting and northing coordinates. Any way to figure out which reference system was used? I know general area where they are located but no clue which CRS was used for the easting and northing and can’t get points anywhere plotted in Utah

[image]

Comment: Which software are you using?